# Implementation of spBLEU

Tags: natural-language, model-evaluation, language-models, machine-translation, bleu

I was looking for a way to compute statistics for evaluation metrics for language translation models and I came across spBLEU. I can’t find any implementations/examples that would help me start. Does anyone have a lead on what I can pursue?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.